# Prepend object using jquery and disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a javascript file using jquery in order to inject the input box on the html page. However, when I inject the input on the page and within a few second the input box disappear. I am wondering why is that happen.

```
function injectArea(data) {
    $('#test').prepend('<input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder=" " value="hi">');
}
```

P.S. I m using twitter bootstrap. not sure if that causes the problem.

when i call the function i do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(#button).click(injectArea);
});
```

This is my html:

```
<form class="form">
    <button id ="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Update Profile</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You're trying to prepend an `<input/>` into a `<textarea>`?

Comment: You need to show how `injectArea` is being used. Something else must be replacing or clearing `$('#test')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fiddle shows that there is nothing wrong with `prepend` or the way you are using it. The issue must come from elsewhere. My guess is that you may have an AJAX callback that fires a few seconds after you call it which is overriding the change you are making to `#test`.

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/jy43A/

---

**Update:**

You said:

> For some reason my page refresh itself.

`#button` is a `<button>` tag. Clicking on it will submit the form and refresh the page (if it targets the current page). use `preventDefault();` to stop the submit default action:

```
function injectArea(data) {
    data.preventDefault();
    $('#test').prepend('<input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder=" " value="hi">');
}
```

You can see that the text box appears, then the page refreshes. This will look different in your case, but it will probably be along the same lines as this:

**The effect WITHOUT preventDefault():**
http://jsfiddle.net/jy43A/3/

And this works:

**The effect WITH preventDefault():**
http://jsfiddle.net/jy43A/2/

More info:

**preventDefault info:**
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: For some reason my page refresh itself. is this a problem on my php file? How do i prevent ajax callback from firing

Comment: Are you making an AJAX request somewhere? Can you show me the HTML for `#button`

Comment: yes i have ajax request before this statement $('#button).... . the html is <form class="form">
            <button id ="button" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Update Profile</button>
          </form>

Comment: @ChadD When you click a button you submit the form which refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using the right method?

`prepend`:

```
<div id="a"></div>

$("#a").prepend("<span>");

<div id="a">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

`insertBefore`:

```
<div id="a"></div>

$("#a").insertBefore("<span>");

<span></span>
<div id="a"></div>
```